# What do the categories in XPrivacy mean?

Tags: xprivacy

In [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) it is unclear to me what the different categories mean. So are obvious, but many are not. What is

1. Accounts - to get the gmail address android is signed in with?
2. Browser - the ability to open a browser?
3. Calendar - the ability to add to the calendar?
4. Calling - the ability to make calls?
5. Dictionary
6. Identification
7. IPC
8. Media
9. What's the difference between network and internet?
10. Phone
11. Shell
12. Storage
13. System

I mean, by definition an app runs on top of the OS/system so wouldn't everything need the system?

Answer (score 0):

For easy usage, data is restricted by category:

- Accounts

  - return an empty account list
  - return an empty account type list
  - return fake account info
  - return empty authorization tokens
  - return an empty list of synchronizations
- Browser

  - return an empty bookmark list
  - return an empty download list
  - return empty search history
- Calendar

  - return an empty calendar
- Calling

  - prevent calls from being placed
  - prevent SIP calls from being placed
  - prevent SMS messages from being sent
  - prevent MMS messages from being sent
  - prevent data messages from being sent
  - return an empty call log
- Clipboard

  - prevent paste from clipboard (both manual and from an application)
- Contacts

  - return an empty contact list

    - content://com.android.contacts
    - content://com.android.contacts/contacts
    - content://com.android.contacts/data
    - content://com.android.contacts/phone_lookup
    - content://com.android.contacts/profile
    - SIM card
- Dictionary

  - return an empty user dictionary
- E-mail

  - return an empty list of accounts, e-mails, etc (standard)
  - return an empty list of accounts, e-mails, etc (Gmail)
- Identification

  - return a fake Android ID
  - return a fake device serial number
  - return a fake host name
  - return a fake Google services framework ID
  - return file not found for folder /proc
  - return a fake Google advertising ID
  - return a fake system property CID (Card Identification Register = SD-card serial number)
  - return file not found for /sys/block/.../cid
  - return file not found for /sys/class/.../cid
  - return a fake input device descriptor
  - return a fake USB ID/name/number
  - return a fake Cast device ID / IP address
- Internet

  - revoke permission to internet access
  - revoke permission to internet administration
  - revoke permission to internet bandwidth statistics/administration
  - revoke permission to VPN services
  - revoke permission to Mesh networking services
  - return fake extra info
  - return fake disconnected state
  - return fake supplicant disconnected state
- IPC

  - Binder
  - Reflection
- Location

  - return a random or set location (also for Google Play services)
  - return empty cell location
  - return an empty list of (neighboring) cell info
  - prevents geofences from being set (also for Google Play services)
  - prevents proximity alerts from being set
  - prevents sending NMEA data to an application
  - prevent phone state from being sent to an application

    - Cell info changed
    - Cell location changed
  - prevent sending extra commands (aGPS data)
  - return an empty list of Wi-Fi scan results
  - prevent activity recognition
- Media

  - prevent recording audio
  - prevent taking pictures
  - prevent recording video
  - you will be notified if an application tries to perform any of these   actions
- Messages

  - return an empty SMS/MMS message list
  - return an empty list of SMS messages stored on the SIM (ICC SMS)
  - return an empty list of voicemail messages
- Network

  - return fake IP's
  - return fake MAC's (network, Wi-Fi, bluetooth)
  - return fake BSSID/SSID
  - return an empty list of Wi-Fi scan results
  - return an empty list of configured Wi-Fi networks
  - return an empty list of bluetooth adapters/devices
- NFC

  - prevent receiving NFC adapter state changes
  - prevent receiving NDEF discovered
  - prevent receiving TAG discovered
  - prevent receiving TECH discovered
- Notifications

  - prevent applications from receiving statusbar notifications (Android 4.3+)
  - prevent C2DM messages
- Overlay

  - prevent draw over / on top
- Phone

  - return a fake own/in/outgoing/voicemail number
  - return a fake subscriber ID (IMSI for a GSM phone)
  - return a fake phone device ID (IMEI): 000000000000000
  - return a fake phone type: GSM (matching IMEI)
  - return a fake network type: unknown
  - return an empty ISIM/ISIM domain
  - return an empty IMPI/IMPU
  - return a fake MSISDN
  - return fake mobile network info

    - Country: XX
    - Operator: 00101 (test network)
    - Operator name: fake
  - return fake SIM info

    - Country: XX
    - Operator: 00101
    - Operator name: fake
    - Serial number (ICCID): fake
  - return empty APN list
  - return no currently used APN
  - prevent phone state from being sent to an application

    - Call forwarding indication
    - Call state changed (ringing, off-hook)
    - Mobile data connection state change / being used
    - Message waiting indication
    - Service state changed (service/no service)
    - Signal level changed
  - return an empty group identifier level 1
- Sensors

  - return an empty default sensor
  - return an empty list of sensors
  - restrict individual sensors:

    - acceleration
    - gravity
    - heartrate
    - humidity
    - light
    - magnetic
    - motion
    - orientation
    - pressure
    - proximity
    - rotation
    - step
    - temperature
- Shell

  - return I/O exception for Linux shell
  - return I/O exception for Superuser shell
  - return unsatisfied link error for load/loadLibrary
- Storage

  - revoke permission to the media storage
  - revoke permission to the external storage (SD-card)
  - revoke permission to MTP
  - return fake unmounted state
  - prevent access to provided assets (media, etc.)
- System

  - return an empty list of installed applications
  - return an empty list of recent tasks
  - return an empty list of running processes
  - return an empty list of running services
  - return an empty list of running tasks
  - return an empty list of widgets
  - return an empty list of applications (provider)
  - prevent package add, replace, restart, and remove notifications
- View

  - prevent links from opening in the browser
  - return fake browser user agent string

    - Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android; en-us) AppleWebKit/999+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/999.9

Source: [XPrivacy GitHub](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy#restrictions)

Comment: It's hard to understand what these actually do. For example "serial number" appears in 3 categories, plus there's an android id.

Comment: Do people just test things out and hope for the best? For example I just blocked an app from getting account information and then it's backup to Google drive failed. It would be nice if there's a more thorough explanation instead of just saying "accounts".